# Hypernatural numbers and Los theorem

Tags: solution-verification, model-theory

Please check my proofs for the following questions:

Choose a free ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\mathbb{N}$ and let $\mathbb{N}^*:=\mathbb{N}^I/\mathcal{U}$. Show with Los theorem:

(a) Prove that $a\leq^*b$ for any $a,b\in \mathbb{N}^*$ if and only if $\exists c \in \mathbb{N}^*: a+^* c = b$ and if it exists, it's unique.

Assume $a\leq^*b \Longleftrightarrow J:=\{i\in\mathbb{N} \mid a_i \leq b_i\}\in \mathcal{U} \Longleftrightarrow \exists c_i: a_i + c_i = b_i.$ Let $c_i$ be equal to zero if $i \notin J$, otherwise let it be $c_i$. The constructed number $c$ has the requested property, since $a_i+c_i=b_i$ on an index set $J\in \mathcal{U}$.

Assume a number $c\in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that $a+^*c=b$ exists. It follows that $a_i + c_i = b_i$ on some index set $K\in\mathcal{U}$ which implies $a_i\leq b_i$ on the index set $K \implies a\leq^* b$ in $\mathbb{N}^*$.

Assume there are two $c, c'$ with the property $a+^*c= b$ and $a +^*c' =b$. This means that $a+^*c= b$ holds on some index set $L_1\in\mathcal{U}$ and $a +^*c' =b$ holds on some index set $L_2\in\mathcal{U}$. Take intersection $L:=L_1 \cap L_2 \in \mathcal{U}$. Since the intersection $L$ is also in an ultrafilter, both properties hold and it follows that $c_i = c'_i$ on $L \implies c=c'$ in $\mathbb{N}^*$.

(b) Prove that $\alpha:\mathbb{N}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{N}^*, a \mapsto a+^*1$ is injective and its image is equal to $\mathbb{N}^*\setminus\{0\}$.

Assume it isn't injective. This means that $\varphi = \exists x, x'\,( x \neq x') \land (x+^*1=x'+^*1)$ should hold on some index set $J\in \mathcal{U}$. Check in natural numbers and get back to the ultraproduct (I don't want to write it out).

(c) Prove that for any $a\in\mathbb{N}^*$ exists $b\in\mathbb{N}^*$ such that either $(b+b)=a$ or $(b+b+1)=a$.

Let $a\in\mathbb{N}^*$. Let $J_0:= \{i\in\mathbb{N}\mid a_i \equiv 0 \pmod 2\}$, $(\mathbb{N}\setminus J_0)= \{i\in\mathbb{N}\mid a_i \equiv 1 \pmod 2\}$. One of this sets is in the ultrafilter and depending on which one exactly we can choose $b$ such that one of the above holds.

(d) Prove that every element $a\in\mathbb{N}^*\setminus \mathbb{N}$ has a predecessor $b\in\mathbb{N}^*\setminus \mathbb{N}$ such that $b+^*1 = a$.

We can construct this number explicitly. $a\in\mathbb{N}^*\setminus \mathbb{N} \implies J:=\{i\in \mathbb{N} \mid a_i > k, k \in \mathbb{N}\}\in\mathcal{U}$. Let $K:=\{i\in \mathbb{N} \mid a_i-1 > k, k \in \mathbb{N}\}$. We can definitely say that $K\subseteq J$. Is $K$ also in the ultrafilter? It has to be, otherwise $J\setminus K$ is in the ultrafilter which implies that $a_i = k+1$ and $a\in\mathbb{N}$, contradiction to $a\in\mathbb{N}^*\setminus \mathbb{N}$. Define $b_i:=a_i-1$ if $i\in K$, otherwise let $b_i$ be zero. Done.

(e) Prove that for any $a\in\mathbb{N}^*\setminus \mathbb{N}$ there exists a number $b\in\mathbb{N}^*\setminus \mathbb{N}$ such that $b+^* n \neq a$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Define $b$ as:
$$
\forall i\in\mathbb{N}: b_i = 
\begin{cases}
a_i/2 & a_i \equiv 0\pmod{2} \\
(a_i+1)/2 & a_i \equiv 1\pmod{2}
\end{cases}
$$
Assume that $b+^*n = a$ is true. Then we can assume that either $a_i \equiv 0\pmod{2}$ or $a_i \equiv 1\pmod{2}$ holds for all $a_i$ otherwise $n$ wouldn't be a constant and
\begin{align*}
    J:= & \{i\in \mathbb{N} \mid b_i + n = a_i \} \in \mathcal{U} \\
    \implies & \{i\in \mathbb{N} \mid b_i = a_i -n \} \in \mathcal{U} \\
    \implies & \{i\in \mathbb{N} \mid a_i = 2a_i -2n \} \in \mathcal{U} \\
    \implies & \{i\in \mathbb{N} \mid a_i = 2n \} \in \mathcal{U}, \\
\end{align*}

implying that $a=2n$ and $a\in\mathbb{N}$, contradiction to $a\in\mathbb{N}^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution appears to be correct. But it is possible to solve this in a much simpler way by applying Łos’s theorem. The case we need is:

> Let $\phi$ be a sentence (in the language of the natural numbers). Then $\mathbb{N}^* \models \phi$ if and only if $\mathbb{N} \models \phi$.

Note that (a), (b), and (c) can all be reduced to a general form: prove $\mathbb{N}^* \models \phi$. In all three cases, it is fairly simple to prove that $\mathbb{N} \models \phi$; we then apply Łos’s Theorem, and we’re done.

(d) is a little tricker. We first show $\mathbb{N} \models \forall a (a = 0 \lor \exists b (b + 1 = a))$. Using Łos’s theorem, we know the same sentence holds in $\mathbb{N}^*$. Now consider some $a \in \mathbb{N}^* \setminus \mathbb{N}$. Clearly, we can’t have $a = 0$, since $0 \in \mathbb{N}$. Now take some $b \in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that $b +^* 1 = a$. Suppose $b \in \mathbb{N}$; then $b +^* 1 = a \in \mathbb{N}$; contradiction. So $b \in \mathbb{N}^* \setminus \mathbb{N}$ and $b +^* 1 = a$, as required.

For (e), just take $b = a +^* 1$. We have $\mathbb{N} \models \forall a \forall n (a + 1 + n \neq a)$, and hence the same holds in $\mathbb{N}^*$ by Łos’s thm.